# why does my url have my domain name at the end?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-routing, google-search-console

My website uses CodeIgniter.  In the routes file i take the language and the page id from the url to get the relevant info for the destination page.

e.g. http://eternalcitytours.com/en/21/Tours/Vatican-Sistine-Chapel-Tour

en is the language. 21 is page id.  and Tours/Vatican-Sistine-Chapel-Tour is just what i chose to be in this bit of the url for seo purposes.

My problem is that in Google Webmaster Tools under the HTML Improvements tab i often get errors for duplicate titles and duplicate descriptions.  This is because it says it found 2 pages with duplicate meta content and the address of the pages are:

http://eternalcitytours.com/en/21/Tours/Vatican-Sistine-Chapel-Tour
http://eternalcitytours.com/en/21/eternalcitytours.com

I can't find any links linking to this second eroneous url.  I don't get why webmaster tools sees a url like no 2 above.

Anyone know why so i can get ride of these duplicate html errors in webmaster tools please???

thanks

Tom

Comment: You haven't provided any code but my guess is your htaccess accepts anything after the `id` so `http://eternalcitytours.com/en/21/` and `http://eternalcitytours.com/en/21/eternalcitytours.com` serve the same. I think that link comes from a relative link on that page, `href="eternalcitytours.com"`.

Comment: @chris85 is probably right and the Google Bots are probably finding and following that link. Also, have you considered looking into the `routes.php` file in codeigniter for getting rid of that `/en/21` and have a much more friendly URL? You could combine routes with a simple url rewrites table to connect your pages. That would also give you the ability to create 404 returns for non-existent pages, which would probably make it a lot easier for you to find that link.

Comment: Thanks chris85.  i had a look at my code for an offending page and searched for all hrefs. the only thing i could find was that there are some occasions where href="#" is used e.g. in my dropdowns on the nav bar... would this be the cause??

Comment: Use the `@` to tag users. I'm not familiar with `hreflang` but those `href`s are relative.

Comment: @chris85 hreflang is commented out i think.

Comment: What is the date the webmaster shows for the date detected? Maybe relative link was present previously?

Comment: @chris85 - it's been coming up for months without any changes to my code...

Comment: Update your question with your code. Everything outside of that is a guess. `htaccess` first, your controller, then the pages code.